# Radio Button: Yes/No or No/Yes

Tags: radio-buttons, default

In some cases, as `No` is the default option for a radio button, should it be placed first instead of `Yes`?

In my opinion, default option should be prioritized to place on left. What's your opinion?

Comment: Randomly alternate Yes/No and No/Yes, just to keep your users attentive !

Comment: It is upvoted for humor purpose, not because it is true

Comment: Your comment is upvoted because it is true.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I would like to advise you not to use Yes/No as radio buttons.

**It is advised to use sentence style labels in imperative style.**

[image]

Now, to answer the question in which order the options should appear, here is what [MS UX style guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) recommends:

> List the options in a logical order, such as most likely to be
>   selected to least, simplest operation to most complex, or least risk
>   to most.

Comment: You should probably still answer the question of which order they should be in. You do that implicitly with the pictures, but never state it directly.

Comment: Ah, this is nice, I don't have to read the question, I can just tell from the options what it is about. I learned something today. +1

Comment: Interesting how your answer implicitly suggests doing yes/no (or positive/negative) but it presents the answer in a negative/positive order. 8) Great answer though!

Comment: *Why* is it "advised to use sentence style labels in imperative style"? I, for one, would much rather read "Include pictures? Yes/No" than time-wasting, convoluted, space-hogging versions that seem to creep slowly towards "Do you want to include the pictures, David? Yes please, I want to include the pictures. Pictures are nice!/No, I do not want to include the pictures. I'm more of a text sort of guy." as the years go by.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: That's excatly the point. If the buttons (or radio buttons in this case) only read Yes and No, you are obligated to read the question above. If the radiobuttons are labeled with an imperative, you only need to read the imperatives ("Include" and "Do not") and you're basically done! I am not advocating to use long sentences or put your life story as the radio button's label. You need to reduce to the minimum, but not further than that!

Comment: @BartGijssens But "Include pictures? Yes/No" contains zero repetition. In your example (which is, of course, much more sensible than my hyperbolic one), the phrase "include pictures" is repeated and there's the redundant header "Printing options". The yes/no version makes the user read four words; the sentence version makes them read eight.

Comment: Actually the word count is in both cases the same: "Print pictures yes no" = 4 vs "Include Do not include" = 4. But it's not about the number of words. Less words is not necessarily better. I could reduce your example even further: "Pictures? Yes / No" = 3. While we are at it, why not just reduce it to: "Pics? Yes / No".
I am not saying repetition is bad, I am saying your argument about being verbose or not is not relevant. For instance: "Dear David, I know you may be more of a text kind of guy, but pictures are sort of cool, you should consider then. Shall I include them for you? Yes / No.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's not about the word count or repetition, it's about the number of items that you must process. "Do X? Yes / No" always requires 2: *X* then the answer, and the *X* must remain in a human's working memory while deciding on a choice (granted 2 items is small, average human is 5-9). On the other hand: "<Irrelevant>: Do X / Do Y" requires attention to only 1 (the resulting action only), with no use of working memory. Even if the latter has more words, it has the minimal number of "attention items".

Comment: @DavidRicherby But where I think your concern is coming from, which is valid, is the risk of this getting into that irritating (at least to me) Microsoft-esque overly-task-oriented realm, where clarity of what's actually going on is lost (e.g. "Change the way I am presented with a document => What do you want to do? I want to refer to pictures as I read / I want to read without distraction." - this is no good.)

Comment: Grammatically that is not imperative, but infinitive.

Answer (score 70):

Why won't you rather use a checkbox that says "include pictures"?

A YES/NO is 1/0, therefore a case for a checkbox.

Comment: +1, good point. If there are only 2 mutually exclusive options, you can just as well go with a checkbox.

Comment: I don't think a checkbox is equivalent to the described radio buttons. I have always felt that a checkbox is "less explicit" about the choice being made. Not checking/unchecking a checkbox kind of conveys that an optional choice is simply skipped, whereas a yes/no pair of radio buttons explicitly says that, no matter whether *yes* or *no* is chosen, a choice is made with all of its consequences. It is comparable to textboxes left empty vs. text boxes where users explicitly (have to) enter *no, thanks*, *N/A*. The input is the same, but what they convey to users feels different in a subtle way.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Checkbox is for choices about yes or not, where the default can (but doesn't necessarily mean) that you've skipped the choice. A radio button implies that you need to select **one of the following choices, or none at all**. I think a checkbox looks better in this case.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Not quite; radio buttons generally do not allow selecting *none at all* (at least most implementations I am aware of do not allow a deselection). That is exactly why I think when the choices are *Yes* and *No*, and it should be explicit that **you *need* to select one of the choices**, two radio buttons can be better suited than a single checkbox.

Comment: To express it from a user perspective, with two concrete examples: Imagine the option *Color nodes in graph view* in some settings dialog box - that's perfectly fine as a checkbox. It is clear what it does, it is a simple setting that can be changed if one doesn't like it, and nothing is broken when it is skipped. Now, imagine the option *Install super-ad-spy-backdoor-toolbar* in an installer - I definitely feel better when there is a radio button to select *No* than if all I can do is leave a checkbox unchecked and hope. Like I said, same input, but a subtly different feeling for the user.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You don't just need to look at how a control feels. Something that also matters is screen real estate. if you're using radio buttons, you automatically need double the screen real estate, because you need to have room for what's basically 2 controls. If you have a dozen options on a screen (like in a configuration screen), radio buttons will either make the window larger (and intimidating) or crowded (and thus uglier and harder to read) than using checkboxes. Similarly, a checkbox for an optional install allows more room to explain the install itself.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: Agreed, though typically, there is some unused space left toward the end of the line next to a checkbox. Placing anything unrelated there makes the whole layout look cramped. Two grouped radio buttons, on the other hand, can well be placed on the same line, especially if they feature only short captions such as *yes* and *no*, as is the case here. In such situations, the radio buttons do not require any more space than the checkbox.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You still have the problem of which one goes first though, which is what this question wants to solve. Checkboxes completely avoid that problem because there is only one element to align.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It is a strong case for a check box, though, if its initial default state (be it checked or unchecked) is highly likely to be chosen; in which case "skipping" it to accept the default leads to no surprises. If 90% of the time a user does *not* include pictures, then an initially unchecked checkbox to mean "you can choose or you can just ignore this" makes a lot of sense. Your point about check boxes makes the most sense when it's roughly a 50/50 chance (and irreversible side effects are limited, e.g. extra usage of printer ink), which may not be the case here.

Answer (score 9):

It's your call whether it should be Yes/No or No/Yes. But it should be consistent across the entire app. This poses a concern for your reasoning because in some places Yes might be the default option and No might be default somewhere. Even though they are both within the same page / app.

A good workaround would be to use verbs. Save / Don't save is better than Yes / No. This way it's easier to position primary / secondary actions consistently across the app. Additionally, it also helps to separate primary / secondary action using different colors.

In general, the default option should be easier to find - if your website is ltr, then this would intuitively be on the right side.

Don't save on left, save on right

I hope this helps answer your question

Answer (score 5):

I think a good alternative here was to use a toggle switch (like Android) instead of radio buttons.

Comment: That may be true, but it doesn't really answer the question itself. OP wasn't asking for alternatives, or whether the use of radio buttons is appropriate, OP is asking what order the radio buttons should be shown in. Assuming there is a good reason for them having it as radio buttons - what order should they be in?

Comment: Interesting how this answer has a negative score of (currently) -2, while the same answer above (http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/61321/38412 - "use a checkbox") scores +15.

Comment: @CompuChip: Both are poor answers that don't address the question (and I downvoted both accordingly). However at least the other answer gives a little bit of reasoning (albeit briefly).

Comment: The fundamental difference is that in the answer with the checkbox, the question becomes irrelevant. In this answer the question simply remains.

Comment: @CompuChip It's not that interesting. :) That answer appears earlier on the page. By the time you get to this one, you've already got that t-shirt.